# Disable Lua debugger in Redis

Tags: redis, lua

I would like to ensure that clients cannot use Redis' Lua debugger.
I already have ACLs set to prevent use of `SCRIPT` and `EVAL` commands.

I see on https://redis.io/topics/ldb that remote debugging mode can be entered using a CLI flag. Is this also prevented by ACLs, or is there some other method to be aware of?

I do not use LDB at all, so disabling it at build time would be great, if possible.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail exactly what you're doing with Redis? It sounds like you don't trust its clients, but that's contrary to the security model Redis uses.

Comment: Principle of least privilege. I might trust clients for some things but that doesn't mean I allow access for all things. e.g. perhaps those clients are able to be compromised in some way, that should not mean that Redis should then also be open to compromise.

Comment: The point is that with Redis's security model, unless you're doing a ton of other work too, just disabling the Lua debugger isn't really going to make a difference.

Comment: The LDB has CVE's. Unfortunately I am unable to update to a newer version at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Redis Lua debugger is a remote debugger, and it needs Redis server and client to work together.

You can disable the `SCRIPT` command, either by `rename-command` configuration or ACL. Although the client can enter the debugging mode, Redis server will refuse `SCRIPT DEBUG` subcommand, and the remote debugging won't work.

> I do not use LDB at all, so disabling it at build time would be great, if possible.

You cannot disable it at build time, unless you modify the source code to remove the feature, and rebuild it.